whatsdesk - opening whatsapp-share-links
I'm  using whatsdesk for whatsapp-chatting on my Kubuntu-PC. This works well.
But whatsdesk doesn't open share-links. When I click a whatsapp-share-button in firefox, firefox sends the link to whatsdesk and whatsdesk comes to the front or whatsdesk starts if it isn't running yet but nothing happens.
Any idea to this?
